# \n and other spaces are not being replaced by <br/>

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching some data from an API and that data has '\n'.

I tried doing this

```
 const data = data.replace(
    new RegExp('\r?\n', 'g'),
    ' <br/>'
  );
```

and then

```
<p> {data} </p>
```

But the spaces are not being replaced. Instead I am seeing this:

```
STEP1 <br/> <br/>
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz by 'other spaces' I meant "↵ ↵ "

Comment: I tried adding the ↵ ↵ inside the regex but the result is the same

Comment: @Calculuswhiz sorry could you rephrase that please ?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz this is how it is looking inside the html

 'Cooking in a cajun spice and cayenne pepper marinade makes this fish super succulent and flavoursome. Top with a zesty dressing and serve in a tortilla for a quick, fuss-free main that's delightfully summery.<br/><br/>On a large plate, mix the cajun'

Comment: @Calculuswhiz.  const instructions = meal?.strInstructions.replace(
    new RegExp('\r?\n', 'g'),
    '<br/>'
  );

Comment: Your data object is a string and I guess you're expecting that the html tags in that string shall be interpreted by react. If you want the tag to be interpreted, then you'll need to use the prop `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` on the <p> tag as described here https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because React escapes html in strings when you put them inside of JSX expressions.

One way you could do this might be to convert each line into its own item in an array and render the `<br />` tag in between them.

```js
const dataString = `Line1
Line2
Line3`;

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            {dataString.split("\n").map((line) => (
                <React.Fragment>
                    {line}
                    <br />
                </React.Fragment>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

In my opinion using `<br/>` isn't the most ideal way to add line breaks to a situation like yours. Instead I would put each line in its own `<p>` tag.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it worked as a charm :). I will create seperate <p> instead